# MVC5 - Create relation between users (Parent <->Student)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

using MVC5 EF Code First, I need to implement school ERP that a user can have rule of either Teacher, Student, Parent, Principle...

I cant figure out what is the best practice to implement the relationship between users.
Say Parent <-> Student, Teacher <-> Student.
Also each rule has a different set of properties.

Please give me a lead.

Comment: Have you even attempted to do this? Please don't post on stack without showing any attempt made to solve your own issue

Comment: Start with `Person`. You can use `roles` or Teacher -> person, Parent -> person, etc.